# How do I add description to FromHeaderAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

`FromHeader` only has a `Name` property and doesn't have description. How do I change the description?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromHeader] string Authorization)
{
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your csproj to use xml documentation:
[image]

Update your program.cs
[image]

Then your xml comments will show, like mine:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should include the using System.ComponentModel then add an annotation to the controller method like this:

```
[Description("This description will appear in docs")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromHeader] string Authorization)
        {
       }
```

Hope help you.

Comment: Actually I tried this one. Also tried this [FromHeader][Required]Description("This")] string Authorizations. They don't work